# Using an Arduino as EMG sensor

Tags: arduino

When I search online for EMG sensors, I often see these sensors are just made of a few transistors, resistors and sometimes diodes. Also I once read on a site that EMG sensors are some kind of modified voltmeters. But while I managed to make a voltmeter from an Arduino, I haven't been able to make an EMG sensor from an Arduino.

Does someone know whether it is possible to make an EMG sensor from an Arduino and how they did achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about electronic circuit design.

Comment: Isn't cheaper to buy one https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest problem here is that of dynamic range.  EMG signals are AC voltages typically in the low mV range and would need a gain of 100 or so to get them up to +/-2.5V, then a simple offset circuit to convert that to 0-5V for the Arduino analog inputs. However, that's not the whole story, since the small EMG signals can ride up and down on large low-frequency background voltages.  Your AC amplifier would need a high-pass filter to remove those, or they could drive it off-scale which would prevent the EMG from getting through.  If you reduce the gain to keep things in range, the EMG will be a rather small part of the 10-bit ADC range on the Arduino.

So the thing to ask is what is the point of using the Arduino in the first place?  If you are going to connect it to a computer in order to look at the EMG signals, then why not just skip the Arduino and use the computer's sound card? The Mic input probably has enough gain already, and you get at least 16-bit resolution to handle any large non-EMG background that wasn't filtered out.

IMPORTANT!  EMG measurements require direct electrical connection to the body.  For safety, you should make certain that your recording equipment is electrically isolated.  If you use *only* a standalone Arduino, you should power it from batteries.  If you use a computer, it should be a laptop running on batteries, with no other connections to ground.

Answer (score 0):

> I often see these sensors are just made of a few transistors,
>   resistors and sometimes diodes.

That's true for pretty much all electronics devices...

> Does someone know whether it is possible to make an EMG sensor from an
>   Arduino and how they did achieve this?

You cannot build an EMG sensor from an Arduino. But you read sensor values with an Arduino either through serial interfaces or by measuring voltages.

With a bare Arduino you can neither measure negative voltages nor can you amplify small signals. (we're in the µV range here...)

Just buy something ready or learn more on electronics